# Multiplication of each slice of a 3D matrix with 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I try to use `svd` in my work which will return the vector as below.

```
A=rand(10,5);
b=rand(10,5,100);
[U, S , V]=svd(A);
```

What I'm trying to do is to multiply each slice of `b` with `U`. With one specific slice, this operation is valid:

```
c=U'*b(:,:,1);
```

However when I try to use a vectorized method as below, it return array dimensions mismatch error.

```
Utran=U.';
c = cellfun(@(x) x.*b,num2cell(Utran,[1 2]),'UniformOutput',false);
```

I could probably use loop for the first method, but it's not efficient if I have a large matrix. Any idea what's my mistake here?

Comment: This can be solved with a simple for loop. Why not?

Comment: Well, that 100 slices is just an example, in real world I'm dealing with more than 50K slices. So for future proof, I might want to start vectorize my code :)

Comment: Vectorization != fast. MATLAB's JIT compiler is very good and often for loops are equally fast.

Comment: Okay, but I can't compare and make a decision since the vectorized code doesn't work

Comment: Especially `cellfun` in many times is slower than for loop...

Comment: @GregorIsack "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"-Donald Knuth. Why optimize a piece of code that you don't know if its critical for your application?

Comment: But the function work if you omit the `[1 2]`. Why in the specific slice you did matrix multiplication, and in the cellfun you did element wise multiplication?

Comment: @AnderBiguri oh well, make sense haha.

Comment: Loops are OK.  Vectorize your code if it makes it shorter and more readable. Readable code is the code that is worth most. Optimize your code only if it's a bottleneck. Use `profile` before you optimize anything. And include the non-optimized code if the optimization harms readability.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm using the 2017b, the latest I presume. Doing that will return an error of "arguments must be 2-D, or at least one
argument must be scalar." and `U'.*b` will return mismatch. EDIT: guess I'll stick with loops for now.

Comment: BTW: Don't forget to pre-allocate your output array before that loop that you're writing! :)

Answer (score 0):

The following is a vectorized solution.

Not sure if it's faster than using loops; and even if it is, note that it uses more memorry for intermediate computations:

```
result = permute(sum(permute(conj(U), [1 3 4 2]).*b), [4 2 3 1]);
```